# I am trying to sum the columns of specific headers in a particular row but I am getting total sum of all columns of that row irrespective of header

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

'I am trying to sum the columns of specific headers in a particular row but I am getting total sum of all columns of that row irrespective of header. Can someone please tell me my mistake?Please see the attached image for sample input output.[image]

```
Dim DSum As Integer
Dim PSum As Integer
With wsn
    NIMsLastRow = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    NIMsLastCol = Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 2 To NIMsLastRow
        DSum = 0
        PSum = 0
        For k = 2 To NIMsLastCol
            If .Cells(1, k).Value = "LTE 1900Deployed" Or "LTE 2500Deployed" Or "LTE 800Deployed" Or "UnassignedDeployed" Then
                DSum = DSum + CInt(.Cells(j, k).Value)
            End If
            If .Cells(1, k).Value = "LTE 1900Planning" Or "LTE 2500Planning" Or "LTE 800Deployed" Or "UnassignedPlanning" Then
                PSum = PSum + CInt(.Cells(j, k).Value)
            End If
        Next k
        .Cells(j, NIMsLastCol + 1).Value = DSum
        .Cells(j, NIMsLastCol + 2).Value = PSum
    Next j
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a re-write to use Select Case which will also solve the error around your test conditions. Remember to use Option Explicit at the top of your module to check your variable declarations. And is it possible that you might need Double for your DSum and PSum? Note I have exchanged Integers for Longs to avoid potential overflow (happens with large numbers when trying to store something too big for the declared datatype)

```
Option Explicit 'Always use Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wsn As Worksheet
Set wsn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NIMSCarrierCount") 'assumption this is correct sheet assigment

Dim DSum As Long 'use Long to avoid potential overflow
Dim PSum As Long
Dim NIMsLastRow As Long 'declare all variables
Dim NIMsLastCol As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

With wsn

    NIMsLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    NIMsLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 2 To NIMsLastRow

        DSum = 0
        PSum = 0

        Dim testValue As String

        For k = 2 To NIMsLastCol

            testValue = .Cells(1, k)

            Select Case testValue

            Case "LTE 1900Deployed", "LTE 2500Deployed", "UnassignedDeployed"
                DSum = DSum + CLng(.Cells(j, k))

            Case "LTE 1900Planning", "LTE 2500Planning", "UnassignedPlanning"
                PSum = PSum + CLng(.Cells(j, k))

            Case "LTE 800Deployed"

              DSum = DSum + CLng(.Cells(j, k))
              PSum = PSum + CLng(.Cells(j, k))

            End Select

        Next k

        .Cells(j, NIMsLastCol + 1).Value = DSum
        .Cells(j, NIMsLastCol + 2).Value = PSum

    Next j

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Approach is much better than OP's. A logical issue though: you have **LTE 800Deployed** in both case statements (looking at OP's question so do they). In this situation, if the scenario is **LTE 800Deployed**, it will only ever go into the first case statement and never hit the second case. So maybe it should be an **IF** statement rather than a **SELECT** as I suspect OP wants to hit both **SUMS** for **LTE 800Deployed**?

Comment: Possibly just have a third case for **LTE 800Deployed** where it adds to both sums?

Comment: Thanks Robbie, QHar and Zac. I am a New Bee and I am learning vba by working on my very first assignment of excel VBA( to ease out my tasks in excel). Had it not been for SO and people like you, I would have been lost forever. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: No worries. Take a moment to review my answer above as there are some additional things to notice e.g. Option Explicit, using Long, declaring all variables, avoiding activesheet implicit references.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement has been written incorrectly.

The `Or "LTE 2500Deployed"` is being evaluated to True for every query.

You need to specify fully for each parameter as such
`.Cells(1, k).Value = "LTE 1900Deployed" Or .Cells(1, k).Value = "LTE 2500Deployed" Or...`